# Custom Cart Rule Action Condition in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, promotions, sales-rule

I have a custom quote item attribute (v_code) and I want to use this when creating a cart sales rule.

Scenario: If a cart item has a v_code, it's included/excluded from the discount.

I've managed to add it to the Conditions section but I am unable to add it to the Action conditions.

I would like to add it here.

[image]

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

here's the answer.

Create di.xml file:

```
....

    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine">
        <plugin name="pluginnamehere"
                type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\SalesRule\Condition\FileNameCondition"/>
    </type>
....
```

file: Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\SalesRule\Condition\FileNameCondition.php

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\SalesRule\Condition;

use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\FileNameCondition;

class FileNameCondition
{
    /**
     * @param Combine $subject
     * @param array $result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetNewChildSelectOptions(
        Combine $subject,
        array $result
    ): array
    {
        $groupLabel = __('Cart Item Attribute');
        $conditionAdded = false;

        foreach ($result as &$condition) {
            if (isset($condition['value'], $condition['label'])
                && is_array($condition['value'])
                && $condition['label']->getText() === $groupLabel->getText()
            ) {
                $condition['value'][] = $this->getCondition();
                $conditionAdded = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$conditionAdded) {
            // if group of "Cart Item Attribute" not founded then add condition separately
            $result[] = $this->getCondition();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    private function getCondition(): array
    {
        return [
            'value' => \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Rule\Condition\NewActionCondition.php::class,
            'label' => __('My new action condition')
        ];
    }
}
...
```

file: Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Rule\Condition\NewActionCondition.php

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Rule\Action;

use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Context;

class NewActionCondition extends AbstractCondition
{
    /**
     * @var Yesno
     */
    protected $sourceYesno;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Yesno $sourceYesno
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Yesno $sourceYesno,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->sourceYesno = $sourceYesno;
    }

    /**
     * Load attribute options
     * @return $this
     */
    public function loadAttributeOptions()
    {
        $this->setAttributeOption([
            'new_action_condition' => __('My new action condition')
        ]);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get input type
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInputType()
    {
        return 'select';
    }

    /**
     * Get value element type
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValueElementType()
    {
        return 'select';
    }

    /**
     * Get value select options
     * @return array|mixed
     */
    public function getValueSelectOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('value_select_options')) {
            $this->setData(
                'value_select_options',
                $this->sourceYesno->toOptionArray()
            );
        }
        return $this->getData('value_select_options');
    }

    /**
     * @param AbstractModel $model
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate(AbstractModel $model)
    {
        //insert here your validation code
        return true;
    }
}
...
```

Cheers :D

Sorry for the delay